# Rename [lego-harry-potter] and [lego-harry-potter-2] to [lego-harry-potter-years-1-4] and [lego-harry-potter-years-5-7]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Currently, we have the tag [lego-harry-potter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter) for *[Lego Harry Potter: Years 1–4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Harry_Potter:_Years_1%E2%80%934)* and [lego-harry-potter-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter-2) for *[Lego Harry Potter: Years 5–7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Harry_Potter:_Years_5%E2%80%937)*. To my knowledge, the two games have never been marketed under those shortened names, and they are a relic of when we had a 25 character limit for tags.

Now that we have a 35 character tag limit, I'd like to recommend the following tag renames:

- [lego-harry-potter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter) → [lego-harry-potter-years-1-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4)
- [lego-harry-potter-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter-2) → [lego-harry-potter-years-5-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter-years-5-7)

We can keep the old tags as synonyms if we'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems reasonable. This is now done:

- [lego-harry-potter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter) → [lego-harry-potter-years-1-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4)
- [lego-harry-potter-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter-2) → [lego-harry-potter-years-5-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter-years-5-7)